# Any Cocoapods for Popover menu in UITableViewCell for iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, popover, cocoapods

I have an application which is using UITableViewController. And I try to implement a popover menu for each Cell as below (Moke app):

[image]

When the user taps on one cell, the app will display a popover menu, when the user taps on one menu item. It will trigger an action with associated cell information. For example, IndexPath.

I am using [PopoverView](https://github.com/runway20/PopoverView) to implement this feature. Because PopoverView API needs showPopoverAtPoint parameter which is CGPoint:

```
[PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:point inView:self withContentView:aView delegate:self];
```

I have to register a UITapGestureRecognizer to catch the tap event

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
singleTap.delegate = self;
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

And then display the popover.

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == tap.state) {
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)tap.view;
    CGPoint p = [tap locationInView:tap.view];
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray* barbuttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    UIBarButtonItem * twitterButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"twitter"
                                                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                       target:self
                                                                       action:@selector(twitterButton:)];

    twitterButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    [barbuttonsArray  addObject:twitterButton];


    [toolbar setItems:barbuttonsArray  animated:NO];

    [PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:p inView:tableView withContentView:toolbar  delegate:nil];
}
```

}

Also I put a UIToolbar in PopoverView to display a toolbar with some menuItems. In this implementation, I need to use UITapGestureRecognizer to handle tap event. Can I do it in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and get the CGPoint? Also when the PopoverView is showing, it disables all other gestures such as scroll or tap another cell. I don't want the user to tap off the popoverview when it is displaying. The PopoverView should dismiss automatically when the user tries to do something else, eg: scroll the table view.

Recap the questions:

1) Is any cocoapod available for this popover menu in UITableViewCell?

2) If no, Can I get CGPoint from didSelectRowAtIndexPath rather than using UITapGestureRecognizer?

3) How to enable gestures when PopoverView is showing and automatically dismiss it?

Thanks in advance.

Jake

Comment: I found QBPopupMenu. It looks good. I'm still working on it and see whether it fits my requirement or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't know exactly what cocoapod can do this.
2. I think you can using the code below in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

> ```
> UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
>
> CGFloat pointY = ((int)(cell.frame.origin.y - tableView.contentOffset.y)/cell.frame.size.height)*cell.frame.size.height;
> ```

1. I konw little about PopoverView, I always do this all by myself using UIView.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I also need X to show the arrow. Maybe I can make it simpler, just show the tooltip on the top when the user taps the cell.